# How to be notified by email when there is a commit of some specific files in SVN?

Tags: svn

In my company there is different dev teams, all of us use SVN.

We share only some files in SVN repository. When one or more of this shared files, are modified and commited, sometimes others teams may not be informed and this can cause a exception in compilation or runtime error that takes many time to be identified and resolved.

IS there a possibility to create email notification when a commit is done on a some specific files in SVN ?

Comment: What OS is your svn server running?

Comment: Windows is the OS where my svn server run.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I'll read the manual of commit hooks to try to customize the script to my specific need as suggested

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with an appropriate `post-commit` svn hook.

A common setup is to use the template `hooks/post-commit.tmpl` in the svn repo to trigger email notifications on every commit, usually sent to a mailing list of the dev team.

In the most basic setup the hook sends the full diff of every commit, of all files, to everyone. In your specific case, it seems you want to customize the script to send the list of changed files instead of the full diff, and also filter by specific paths you are interested in. The `svnlook` command should be helpful for this, especially the `changed` subcommand.

Here's a primitive example hook script which generates the list of changed files in `branches/feature1`:

```
#!/bin/sh
svnlook changed "$1" -r "$2" | grep ^....branches/feature1/ | mailx -s "svn summary: $1 $2" team@example.com
```

I posted a short article on setting up and testing hooks, I think it should help:

http://www.janosgyerik.com/setup-and-test-svn-post-commit-hook-to-send-commit-log/

Answer (score 0):

You can't use SVN as CVS. You probably mean you are using it as Version Control System. CVS is a different VCS.

Yes:

Read the subversion manual for **commit hooks**. They'll also have the information of which files have been modified.

The subversion manual is really good. You should read it.

Comment: Yes, It's a mistake. I mean CVS. I will correct it in the question.